# Como fazer para corrigir esse erro, e consegui enxergar essa outra tabela em minha view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6, razor

Preciso fazer um `select` com duas tabelas e jogar o resultado para um `PagedList`. Mas quando faço a query, retorna o erro:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'PagedList.IPagedList' to 'PagedList.IPagedList<>'. 
>   An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?) C:\IIS\Sistema\Controllers\TitController.cs

Porém quando eu retiro o `Join`, ele não retorna o erro.
Como fazer para corrigir esse erro, e consegui enxergar essa outra tabela em minha *view*?

Segue o código abaixo:

```
public ActionResult ConTitulos(int? Pagina, string Pesquisa, decimal? NProtocolo, For model)
{
        var entities = new Model();
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Pesquisa) || Pagina.HasValue)
        {

            var results = entities.For
                .Join(entities.Dev,
                t => t.For_Dev_ID,
                h => h.Dev_ID,
                (t, h) => new
                {
                t.For_Nome,
                h.Dev_Nome
                })
                .Where(b => b.Protocolo == NProtocolo).AsEnumerable();

            var pageIndex = Pagina ?? 1;
            model.ProcuraResultados = results.ToPagedList(pageIndex, RecordsPerPage);


        }
        if (model.ProcuraResultados != null && model.ProcuraResultados.Count == 1)
        {
            foreach (var item in model.ProcuraResultados)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Devedores", new { id = item.For_ID });
            }

        }
        return View(model);
}
```

**View**

```
@model Sistema.Models.for
@{
  ViewBag.Title = "Consulta de Devedores";
}
@using PagedList.Mvc;
<h2>Consulta de Devedores</h2>
<div id="page-wrapper">
  <div class="content-wrapper">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        @using (Html.BeginForm("ConTitulos", "Devedores", FormMethod.Get))
        {
            <table width="100%">
                <tr>
                    <td class="tblNormal">Nº do Protocolo</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="tblNormal">
                        <input type="text" name="NProtocolo" onkeypress="FiltraTecla(event);" size="10" maxlength="10" value="">
                        @*@Html.EditorFor(model => model.TIT_PRT_CRT, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", name= "NProtocolo",size = "10", maxlength = "10", value = "" } })*@
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            if (Model.ProcuraResultados != null && Model.ProcuraResultados.Count > 1)
            {
                <div>
                    <br />
                    <table class="table">
                        <tr>
                            <th>Devedor</th>
                            <th>Fornecedor</th>
                        </tr>
                        @foreach (var item in Model.ProcuraResultados)
                        {
                            <tr>
                                <td class="control-label">@item.Dev_nome</td>
                                <td class="control-label">@item.For_Nome</td>
                                <td>
                                    @Html.ActionLink("Alterar", "AltDevedor", new { id = @item.DEV_ID }, null)
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        }
                    </table>
                </div>
                @Html.PagedListPager(Model.ProcuraResultados, page => Url.Action("ConTitulos", new RouteValueDictionary()
      {
           { "Pagina", page },
           { "Apresentante", Model.Dev_nome },
           { "Devedor", Model.For_Nome }
      }),
      PagedListRenderOptions.PageNumbersOnly)
            }
        }
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Bem-vindo Germano. Pode postar sua `view` também?

Comment: Coloquei a View tb!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cara, tenta isso.

```
@model Sistema.Models.for
@{
  ViewBag.Title = "Consulta de Devedores";
}
@using PagedList.Mvc;
<h2>Consulta de Devedores</h2>
<div id="page-wrapper">
  <div class="content-wrapper">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        @using (Html.BeginForm("ConTitulos", "Devedores", FormMethod.Get))
        {
            <table width="100%">
                <tr>
                    <td class="tblNormal">Nº do Protocolo</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="tblNormal">
                        <input type="text" name="NProtocolo" onkeypress="FiltraTecla(event);" size="10" maxlength="10" value="">
                        @*@Html.EditorFor(model => model.TIT_PRT_CRT, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", name= "NProtocolo",size = "10", maxlength = "10", value = "" } })*@
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            if (Model.ProcuraResultados != null && Model.ProcuraResultados.Count > 1)
            {
                <div>
                    <br />
                    <table class="table">
                        <tr>
                            <th>Devedor</th>
                            <th>Fornecedor</th>
                        </tr>
                        @foreach (var item in Model.ProcuraResultados)
                        {
                            <tr>
                                <td class="control-label">@item.Dev_nome</td>
                                <td class="control-label">@item.For_Nome</td>
                                <td>
                                    @Html.ActionLink("Alterar", "AltDevedor", new { id = @item.DEV_ID }, null)
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        }
                    </table>
                </div>
                @Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("ConTitulos", new RouteValueDictionary()
      {
           { "Pagina", page },
           { "Apresentante", Model.Dev_nome },
           { "Devedor", Model.For_Nome }
      }),
      PagedListRenderOptions.PageNumbersOnly)
            }
        }
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Qual foi a alteração que você fez?

Comment: Somente no  @Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("ConTitulos", new RouteValueDictionary()

Comment: A minha lógica da view está correta, o problema está em meu Controller que não envia os dados da querie para a variável ProcuraResultados
onde será utilizada para a lógica da paginação.

model.ProcuraResultados = results.ToPagedList(pageIndex, RecordsPerPage);

Comment: Existe um tipo Procuradados? ou você está tentando mandar anonimo para a viu?

Comment: O procurador que você fala é o .Select?

Comment: ProcuraResultados

Comment: O Procurador é um tipo pagedlist dentro do model.

Comment: Tudo bem, mas a sua view está esperando um  @model Sistema.Models.for e você não está retornando esse tipo no seu var results = entities.For
                .Join(entities.Dev,
                t => t.For_Dev_ID,
                h => h.Dev_ID,
                (t, h) => new
                {
                t.For_Nome,
                h.Dev_Nome
                })
                .Where(b => b.Protocolo == NProtocolo).AsEnumerable();

Comment: Alterei a lógica da pagedList para ajax e deu certo!

Answer (score 0):

Isto não devolve `List<for>`:

```
var results = entities.For
            .Join(entities.Dev,
            t => t.For_Dev_ID,
            h => h.Dev_ID,
            (t, h) => new
            {
            t.For_Nome,
            h.Dev_Nome
            })
            .Where(b => b.Protocolo == NProtocolo).AsEnumerable();
```

Isto devolve um objeto anônimo com duas propriedades: `For_Nome` e `Dev_Nome`. Isto vai conflitar com o que temos na *View*, por isso o erro:

```
@model Sistema.Models.for
```

Como você manda para a *View* uma `IPagedList`, troque para:

```
@using PagedList
@model IPagedList
```

Comment: Não resolve, pois não tenho nenhum model chamado Pagedlist

Comment: @GermanoSampaio Editei a resposta.